# how to hide app name from Facebook wall post

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I have registered an app on my Facebook account, And I am posting Photos from app to Facebook wall post, So It's showing shared via "XYZApp". So I want to remove/hide app name from post.
Check Attachment[image]

I have Used

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(bm).build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(photo).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup ContentProvider :

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}"
       android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
       android:exported="true"/>
```

Then add SharePhotoContent Model into content.

```
 public void dialogShare(Bitmap imagePath){
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(imagePath)
            .setCaption("StudyTutorial")
            .build();
    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();
    shareDialog.show(content);
}
```

Also to share link content use below method :

```
 public static void shareMessageOnFacebook(Activity activity, CallbackManager 
 callbackManager, String msg) {


    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new 
  FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            L.e("FacebookError", loginResult.toString());
            if (loginResult.getAccessToken() != null) {
                ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("app url"))
                        .setQuote(msg)
                        .build();

                ShareDialog.show(activity, content);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

            L.e("FacebookError", exception.getMessage());

        }
    });
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(activity, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it's still same, showing app name. Is there any setting on Facebook developer account ?